# Change HTML title after certain seconds?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to change my page's title with html/javascript after a certain amount of seconds. I know it's possible to change the title but I want to do it automatically after a certain amount of seconds, specifically about 6 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

To change the title, you can use `document.title=newtitle`.

To do an action after a set amount of time, you can use `setTimeout(yourfunction, milliseconds)`.

To do the task you're asking for, you'll need :

```
setTimeout(
  function(){ 
    document.title="New title!" 
  }, 
  6000  // 6000 milliseconds = 6 seconds
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) to create a delay.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    document.title = "New Title!";
}, 6000); // 6 seconds
```

The `setTimeout` function takes two parameters, a function to call, and a delay in milliseconds. It simply calls the function after the given delay.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
var didChangeTitle = false;
if (!didChangeTitle){
    setTimeout(doInterval(), 6000);
}

function doInterval(){
    document.title = "new title"
    didChangeTitle = true;
}
```